# How can I list all nix store paths referenced in a build generation?

Tags: nixos, nix

I'm trying to debug an issue where a nixos configuration on one machine, has the an application accessible in the path (it's listed in `/run/current-system/sw/bin`), while on another machine with the same nixos configuration (minus `hardware-configuration.nix` etc), it does not.

How can I query all the store paths for a Nixos generation? This will help me debug the issue by comparing these it between machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nix-build -E "(import <nixpkgs/nixos> { configuration = /etc/nixos/configuration.nix; }).system"
```

This will build and output the store path, though it's limited to the **current** build generation.

And then one can use  `nix-store -q --tree /nix/store/...example-path-19.09` which print a `tree` like output of all the paths. Or `nix-store -q -R /nix/store/...example-path-19.09` for a simple list.